# Welcome emails in Ruby

Tags: ruby, email

I'm using Ruby and Devise:Confirmable. A day or so after a new user has registered and confirmed a new trial account we'd like to automatically send him or her a 'follow up email'. Is this something we should also do through devise, or is there a separate gem or process we should implement?

Comment: What does a "follow up" email look like?

Comment: you can schedule it with sidekiq and sidekiq-scheduler; you can use something like maily_herald; you can use actual third-party marketing automation services. there's really no limit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Devise already, you can just overwrite the confirmation controller, try something like this.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
  def show
    super do |resource|
      YourMailerClass.follow_up(resource).deliver_later(wait_until: 1.day.from_now) if resource.errors.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

You also need to update the `routes.rb` file, add the option `controllers: { confirmations: :confirmations }` at the end of the line where you define `devise_for` (restart your server after this).

I'm assuming you already have a background jobs proccesor, like sidekiq

Hope it helps